# Execute a PHP script only for fixed time

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

I have a function which creates a socket connection and listens on a port number for HL7 messages sent by a laboratory machine via TCP.

If the lab machine is not sending anything, my listen function keeps listening. Is there a way to specify that it should listen only for say 10 seconds and then if there are no messages, an error should be thrown?

```
    $address = '0.0.0.0';
    $port = 5600;

    // Create a TCP Stream socket
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // Bind the socket to an address/port
    $bind = socket_bind($sock, $address, $port);

    // Start listening for connections
    socket_listen($sock);

    $client = socket_accept($sock);

    // Read the input from the client
    $input = socket_read($client, 2024);

    // Strip all white spaces from input
    $segs = explode("|",$input);

    // Close the master sockets
    $close = socket_close($sock);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
socket_set_option($sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVTIMEO,array("sec"=>10,"usec"=>0)); // after 10 seconds socket will destroy the connection. Also you can set and uses
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

That the thing you want to measure acts as a client rather implies that you might want to do more than just detect an open TCP connection in your script, e.g. capture some data. Further, the underlying OS has a lot of complex, well tested, reliable and tunable mechanisms for tracking the state of connections.

While you could do as stefo91 suggests and try to manipulate receive timeout, I'm not sure if this is applied in the wait for an initial connection. A better solution would be to [set the socket to non-blocking](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-block.php). Don't forget to either:

- inject some calls to sleep()/usleep() or
- use [socket_select](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php)()

unless you want your script to be burning a lot of resource with nothing to do.

But depending on a lot of information you've not told us about, the right solution might be to run one script as a server, and a second as a monitor. The second could be polling/parsing the output of netstat to check the connection.